# Skipping user input using NPM test

Tags: node.js, reactjs, jestjs

When running the command "NPM run test" NPM runs all of my unit tests but it shows a "watch usage" dialog requiring user input.

I want to be able to run "NPM run test" as a part of my build process so I want to have a way to skip this "watch usage" dialog. I have already tried using --forceExit which doesn't change anything.

Are there any command line parameters I can use to launch "NPM run test" without this dialog? Or alternatively, can I add something to the scripts section of my package.json that will cause this dialog not to be shown?

The scripts section of my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js start",
    "build": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js build",
    "test": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js test --env=jsdom",
    "test-coverage": "npm test -- --coverage",
    "test-json": "npm test -- --coverage --json",
    "eject": "node node_modules/react-scripts/bin/react-scripts.js eject",
    "flow": "node node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow",
    "flow-coverage": "node node_modules/flow-coverage-report/bin/flow-coverage-report.js",
    "flow-coverage-report": "if process.platform === 'win32'; then start ./flow-coverage/index.html; else open ./flow-coverage/index.html; fi",
    "flow-json": "node node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow --json",
    "flow-stop": "node node_modules/flow-bin/vendor/flow stop"
   }
```

The aforementioned dialog:

```
Watch usage
 > Press u to update failing snapshots.
 > Press p to filter by a filename regex pattern.
 > Press t to filter by a test name regex pattern.
 > Press q to quit watch mode.
 > Press Enter to trigger a test run.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
"test": "CI=true react-scripts test --watch=all",
```

this worked for me

Comment: Works on Linux doesn't work on Windows. Tested with node.js LTS Version: `12.17.0`. I used Docker as Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Aswear form `Sandeep P` works for me on Linux (Docker) and fails on Windows machine.

Looks like issue is that `cmd` was used on Windows.

Using this commands on Windows let me achieve desired result:

```
set CI=true
npm test --watch=all
```

Also this modification of `package.json` did the job:

```
  "scripts": {
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "test-once": "CI=true react-scripts test --watch=all",
    "test-once-win": "set CI=true && react-scripts test --watch=all",
  },
```

Comment: I think putting REACT_APP_CI=true in a .env file works aswell in windows, can't test it though.

Answer (score 0):

I have figured out one way to disable watch mode for Jest when running it as "NPM test". When running test-coverage which is listed in the scripts section of the package.json jest doesn't start in watch mode but does coverage instead.

It's not completely what I wanted but at least I can use this to run "NPM run test-coverage" as a part of my build solution.

Answer (score 0):

Setting `process.env.CI = true` in test.js worked for me.